# Is there a django-CMS plugin to make links to objects that have URLs?

Tags: django-cms

I'm using Django 1.4 and django-CMS 2.3.

I have several applications with apphooks, and I want, in django-CMS, to be able to refer to 
an object of an application.

In order to make sustainable links, I'm trying to find a plugin using django-CMS menus or generic foreign keys.

If nothing like this exists, what is the best generic foreign key application? I just made a small plugin using django.contrib.contenttypes that limits the choice to models with a `get_absolute_url` method, but it is just awful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just happened across your question.  I've recently implemented something similar for a couple of projects, here's what I did based on the work by Adam Alton described here: http://adamalton.co.uk/blog/displaying-django-genericforeignkey-as-single-form-field/

<strike>This is **not** a CMSPlugin, however, so, I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but its what I have and I hope it can help others looking for a similar solution.</strike>

As an overview, I have a "Banner" type defined in my models which represents a banner on the front page of my customers' sites.  Each banner can be linked to other content.  In these cases, the link destination could be a Django-CMS page, or one of many other types.  All have the method get_absolute_url defined, although, I don't use introspection to determine this, I just implemented get_absolute_url on all the types that would appear here.  Anyway, here goes:

First, here's the simple model for Banner:

```
class Banner(models.Model):
  short_name       = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
  html             = models.TextField()
  link_text        = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='Learn more')
  destination_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True,
    limit_choices_to={"model__in": ("Page", "Project", "Person", "Client")}
  )
  destination_id   = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  destination      = generic.GenericForeignKey('destination_type', 'destination_id')
  published        = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.short_name
```

Here's my forms.py:

```
import re
from django.forms import ModelForm, ChoiceField
from cms.models import Page
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from apps.your_application.models import Project, Person, Client

class BannerAdminForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Banner
    fields = ("short_name", "html", "link_text", "destination", "link_hash", "published",)

  # GenericForeignKey form field, will hold combined object_type and object_id
  destination = ChoiceField(required=False)  # Note the 'required=False' here.

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BannerAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Combine object_type and object_id into a single 'destination' field
    # Get all the objects that we want the user to be able to choose from

    # Note: The user is going to locate these by name, so we should
    # alphabetize all of these

    available_objects  = list(Page.objects.all().order_by('title_set__title'))
    available_objects += list(Project.objects.all().order_by('title'))
    available_objects += list(Person.objects.all().order_by('name'))
    available_objects += list(Client.objects.all().order_by('name'))

    # Now create our list of choices for the <select> field
    object_choices = []
    object_choices.append(["", "--"])
    for obj in available_objects:
      type_class = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj.__class__)
      type_id = type_class.id
      obj_id = obj.id
      form_value = "type:%s-id:%s" % (type_id, obj_id)  # e.g."type:12-id:3"
      display_text = "%s : %s" % (str(type_class), str(obj))  # E.g. "Client : Apple, Inc."
      object_choices.append([form_value, display_text])

    self.fields['destination'].choices = object_choices

    # If there is an existing value, pre-select it
    if self.instance.destination:
      type_class = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.instance.destination.__class__)
      type_id = type_class.id
      obj_id = self.instance.destination.id
      current_value = "type:%s-id:%s" % (type_id, obj_id)
      self.fields['destination'].initial = current_value

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      #get object_type and object_id values from combined destination field
      object_string = self.cleaned_data['destination']
      matches = re.match("type:(\d+)-id:(\d+)", object_string).groups()
      object_type_id = matches[0]  # get 45 from "type:45-id:38"
      object_id = matches[1]       # get 38 from "type:45-id:38"
      object_type = ContentType.objects.get(id=object_type_id)
      self.cleaned_data['destination_type'] = object_type_id
      self.cleaned_data['destination_id'] = object_id
      self.instance.destination_id = object_id
      self.instance.destination_type = object_type
    except:
      # If anything goes wrong, leave it blank,
      # This is also the case for when '--' is chosen
      # In the drop-down (tsk, tsk, bad code style =/)
      self.cleaned_data['destination_type'] = None
      self.cleaned_data['destination_id'] = None
      self.instance.destination_id = None
      self.instance.destination_type = None

    return super(BannerAdminForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can then get the URL of the destination object by calling
`{% if banner.destination %}{{ banner.destination.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}`
in your templates.

Works well and shouldn't be too tough to use in a CMSPlugin.

[image: This is what it looks like in Django Admin]

EDIT: Actually, I've just implemented this exact same thing as a CMSPlugin Form.  There is essential **zero** differences.  Just remember to add the form to your plugin class in your cms_plugins.py file like so:

```
class CMSBannerPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
  form = BannerAdminForm  #   <==== Don't forget this part
  model = Banner
  name = _("Banner Plugin")
  render_template = "apps/your_application/_banner.html"

  def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    ...
    return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSBannerPlugin)
```

Comment: in your models.py `generic.GenericForeignKey` is `from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey` ?

Comment: I was just looking on dev (1.7) version. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: @mkoistinen This helped me a great deal. Why does it have to be ``ChoiceField(required=False)``?

Comment: @creimers Glad you found it useful. In my implementation, I needed it to be optional, but I guess it could be mandatory. Been awhile since I used this. I have release a generic, reusable CMS plugin for this at https://github.com/mkoistinen/djangocms-styledlink.